# Twitter doesn't provide email address for Rails integration

Tags: devise, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've integrated social logins (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) with a Rails app using Devise and OAuth. The requests and callbacks all work great and users are able to authenticate the app and login efficiently.

My problem is this:

With Devise, my site has the user's email address as the username. So, whenever a user logs in through a social site for the first time, a 'connection' record is stored for their account to show which social sites they've logged in with. If they don't already have an account on my site, one is created with the email address from the callback array. The connection is then stored along with the returned tokens and secrets for later use (FB posts, tweets, etc.).

Unfortunately, Twitter doesn't provide the email address. To circumvent this, I'm asking first-time users that login with Twitter to simply provide an email address so an account can be created. However, I can't figure out what to do if they already have an account on my site. I can't check if they already do since I'm not given an email address to match up. This could ultimately cause a user to have multiple accounts.

So, I'm a bit at a loss, and if anyone has any suggestions, it would be extremely helpful.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store some oauth provider info like {provider, twitter identifier} too to your database and then check twitter oauths based on that instead of the email ID.

The simplest thing to do would be to add a slightly different flow for if the login was via twitter. Ask a first time Twitter login user for the email ID. In your users table, add a column called tw_id and add the users twitter identifier. Next time, if the login is via Twitter, you check the tw_id instead of the provider email and proceed with the normal app flow.